# Running model in GPU using OpenVino

Tags: openvino

I can run model on CPU successfully.
Once run on GPU, I have error as

```
[ ERROR ] Check 'get_element_type().is_dynamic() || get_element_type() == element_type' failed at C:\j\workspace\private-ci\ie\build-windows-vs2019@2\b\repos\openvino\ngraph\core\src\runtime\host_tensor.cpp:174:
Can not change a static element type
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do the [Additional Installation Steps for Intel® Processor Graphics (GPU)](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#Install-GPU) or your model may not work on GPU. Refer to the [Public Pre-Trained Models](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_public_device_support.html) and [Intel's Pre-Trained Models](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_intel_device_support.html) to check the Models Device Support. Also, please ensure that you are following all the [System requirements](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#system_requirements) needed.